# Android deep link gives web page not found rather than taking to app?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to share a link for a product page in my app so I've created a deeplink using an intent filter.

`<activity android:name=".user_link">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Allows the deep link to be used without specifying the app name -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--&lt;!&ndash; URI IL://deeplink &ndash;&gt; ilovezappos://viewproduct-->
            <data android:scheme="ilovezappos" android:host="viewproduct"/>
            <!-- URI http://www.mydeeplink.com -->
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mydeeplink.com"/>

        </intent-filter>`

Now, when I send 'www.mydeeplink.com" in let's say messenger to a phone with the app, what I get is a webpage not found error when the link is clicked upon. I can select the options and then select open in my app but I want the link to automatically go to the .user_link activity. Also If I have to pass data, all I need to do is to attach the ? query in front of the deep link right?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you missed deep link action in your current activity, for handling deep linking? "android:name=".user_link" is .user_link" your name of activity?

Comment: yes user_link is the activity. What do you mean handling deep linking in the activity? For now I just want the activity to launch..

Comment: Ok, well handling deep linking comes later yes.. check this tutorial:
[link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters)
.. for deep linking.. and try to test deep linking from console: 

$ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d <URI> <PACKAGE>

Comment: Same problem. The activity launches but when the link that I'm using http://www.mydeeplink.com/ is opened in an app, the app first goes to the browser and give a page not found error :/

Comment: `code`<intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="example" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
`code`

And then click is your link like: "example://home"

Comment: that's exactly what my code is like..

Comment: <html>
<body>

<h1>

<a>android-app</a>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<a href="example://home">home</a>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<body>

</html>

Comment: Copy comment above and saveit to whatewer.html.. and save it to phone, open this html then on phone and click on link..

Comment: If it's still not working.. then I don't know what is happening here..

Comment: So it's working or not? Oh, yes and add label to your activity tag.. maybe it's this all what we missed..

Comment: it was working all along it seems. It will only open if the link is in embedded in html!  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

to open a deeplink, you must adjust the format. Suppose you access a deeplink from Google Crhome, then the access becomes like this

`intent:#Intent;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;scheme=zxing;end;`

or you can read my stories at https://medium.com/@rakaadinugroho/tutorial-deeplink-android-akuisisi-user-ke-arah-mobile-first-7fada079aa17

Comment: Medium Link:

410
This account is under investigation or was found in violation of the Medium Rules.